# Average over parts in list of lists

Tags: python

I have a big list of lists, something like

```
import numpy as np
np.array([range(1,1000), range(1,1000), range(1,1000)])
```

And I'd like to calculate the average of 50 values each in each column. I'd like to get something like:

```
np.array([[np.mean(range(1,50)), np.mean(range(51,100)), ...], [[np.mean(range(1,50)), np.mean(range(51,100)), ...], ...])
```

But instead of values from 1-1000 I have several text files with one column each, and I packed them together in the np.array with

```
average_list = np.array([ np.genfromtxt("1.txt"), np.genfromtxt("2.txt") ])
```

I tried looping over parts of the list and adding 50 values together, but it doesn't seem to do what I want it to

```
average_list = np.array([ np.genfromtxt("1.txt"), np.genfromtxt("2.txt") ])
new_list = []
n=100
for i in range(len(average_list)):
    for j in range(len(average_list[i])):
        while n < j < n+50:
            average_list[i,j]+=average_list[i,j+1]
            j+=1
            new_list.append(average_list[i,j])
        print new_list
        n+=50
```

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, include your code and research in your question to show what hasn't worked for you. If not, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Comment: What format does your txt file use? Is it plain **[0-9]\*,[0-9]\*,[0-9]\*** ?

Comment: i have several textfiles with one column each and packed them together in the np.array with 
average_list = np.array([
np.genfromtxt("1.txt"),
np.genfromtxt("2.txt")
])

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan yes, i have tried several things like looping over parts of the list and adding 50 values together, but it doesnt' seem to do what i want it to do ...
I'm obviously a noob in programming, so i thought i ask without posting my embarrasing attempts ...
but here you go:
average_list = np.array([ np.genfromtxt("1.txt"), np.genfromtxt("2.txt") ]) 
new_list = []
n=100
for i in range(len(average_list)):
 for j in range(len(average_list[i])):
  while n < j < n+50:
   average_list[i,j]+=average_list[i,j+1]
   j+=1
 new_list.append(average_list[i,j])
 print new_list
 n+=50

Comment: @Tolotos Regardless of your skill level posting code is important as it shows what you tried, it makes your intent clearer and allows people to see what parts of the code you do and don't understand. Everyone had to be a beginner once, so don't worry about it too much. :)

Comment: @Tolotos I edited your post to include the code, but if I have made a mistake please edit the post to correct it, as I may have misunderstood your code (especially the indentation)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple and easy to read solution is to run a `map` over the outer list and run a for loop over the indices of the inner loop at every space of 50.

Here's a demo:

```
length = 3
a = np.array([range(1,10), range(1,10)])
map(lambda y: [np.mean(y[i:i+length]) for i in range(0, len(y), length)], a)
```

The above code takes the average of every 3 elements
You could also use `xrange` if using python2

Answer (score 0):

You can first `reshape` the array so that each row is one of the groups of 50 elements, and then apply `np.mean` to each of those rows, then reshape again.

```
>>> a = np.array([range(1000), range(1000), range(1000)])
>>> b = np.reshape(a, (60, 50))
>>> c = np.apply_along_axis(np.mean, 1, b)
>>> np.reshape(c, (3, 20))
array([[  24.5,   74.5,  124.5,  174.5,  224.5,  274.5,  324.5,  374.5,
         424.5,  474.5,  524.5,  574.5,  624.5,  674.5,  724.5,  774.5,
         824.5,  874.5,  924.5,  974.5],
       [  24.5,   74.5,  124.5,  174.5,  224.5,  274.5,  324.5,  374.5,
         424.5,  474.5,  524.5,  574.5,  624.5,  674.5,  724.5,  774.5,
         824.5,  874.5,  924.5,  974.5],
       [  24.5,   74.5,  124.5,  174.5,  224.5,  274.5,  324.5,  374.5,
         424.5,  474.5,  524.5,  574.5,  624.5,  674.5,  724.5,  774.5,
         824.5,  874.5,  924.5,  974.5]])
```